# Accessing Parent Class' property from child

Tags: php, oop

See the following example (PHP)

```
class Parent
{ 
  protected $_property;
  protected $_anotherP;

  public function __construct($var)
  {
    $this->_property = $var;
    $this->someMethod();  #Sets $_anotherP
  }

  protected function someMethod()
  ...
}

class Child extends Parent
{
  protected $parent;

  public function __construct($parent)
  {
    $this->parent = $parent;
  }

  private function myMethod()
  {
    return $this->parent->_anotherP;  #Note this line
  }
}
```

I am new to OOP and am a bit ignorant.

Here to access the parents property I am using an instance of that class, which seems wrong :S (no need of being i child then). Is there an easy way, so that i can sync the parent properties with the child properties and can directly access $this->anotherP without having to use $this->parent->anotherP ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As your `Child` class is extending your `Parent` class, every properties and methods that are either `public` or `protected` in the `Parent` class will be seen by the `Child` class as if they were defined in the `Child` class -- and the other way arround.

When the `Child` class `extends` the `Parent` class, it can be seen as *"`Child` is a `Parent`"* -- which means the `Child` has the properties of the `Parent`, unless it redefines those another way.

*(BTW, note that "`parent`" is a reserved keyword, in PHP -- which means you can't name a class with that name)*

Here's a quick example of a "parent" class :

```
class MyParent {
    protected $data;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->someMethodInTheParentClass();
    }
    protected function someMethodInTheParentClass() {
        $this->data = 123456;
    }
}
```

And it's "child" class :

```
class Child extends MyParent {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getData() {
        return $this->data; // will return the $data property 
                            // that's defined in the MyParent class
    }
}
```

That can be used this way :

```
$a = new Child();
var_dump($a->getData());
```

And you'll get as output :

```
int 123456
```

Which means the `$data` property, defined in the `MyParent` class, and initialized in a method of that same `MyParent` class, is accessible by the `Child` class as if it were its own.

To make things simple : as the `Child` "is a" `MyParent`, it doesn't need to keep a pointer to... itself ;-)

Comment: yeah. The call to the parent::__construct was what i needed :O

Comment: Oh, yes, that's one of the tricky things, and I didn't think to mention it : if your child class defines a constructor, PHP will not call the constructor of the parent class -- which means you'll have to call it yourself *(see the note on http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php )*

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 4):

This may save you a few hours of searching around.

Remember: Your Child class only inherits the properties DEFINED in the Parent class... So if you instantiate an object using Parent class and then populate it with data, then this data will NOT be available in your child class...

It's super obvious of course, but I'm guessing others may run into the same issue.

**A super simple solution is not to extend anything, simply pass the $object of your parent class into your child class through a constructor. This way you have access to all the properties and methods of the object generated by parent class**

Example

```
class child {

    public parentObject;

    public function __construct($parentObject) {
        $this->parentObject = $parentObject;
    }

}
```

If your $parentObject has a public property $name, then you can access it inside the child class with a function like:

```
public function print_name() {
    echo $this->parentObject->name;
}
```