# how do you access the parent object property in child class

Tags: php

Actually,

This is working fine.. but i want the parent value.
not a child value..

```php
<?php
    class Fruit{
        protected $parentproperty = "parentvalue";// this is parent value       
    }

    class Orange extends Fruit{
        protected $parentproperty = "child value";// here i mentioned once again        
        function showParentProperty(){
            return self::$this->parentproperty;
        }


    }
    $obj = new Orange;
    echo $obj->showParentProperty();

    //conclusion:
    // i want to get the parent value not child. its working fine . but it's displaying chid value


?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Parent Class' property from child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283870/accessing-parent-class-property-from-child)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you mean is this:

```
class Fruit {
    protected $parentproperty = "parent value";
}

class Orange extends Fruit{
    protected $parentproperty = "child value";
    function showParentProperty(){
        return $this->parentproperty; // corrected syntax here
    }
}
```

Then there is no way to do what you want because all nonstatic class properties in PHP are effectively virtual.

You could only use the `parent` keyword if the parent property was static, like this:

```
class Fruit {
    static $parentproperty = "parent value";
}
```

If we 're talking about an instance property, then the only thing you can do is use another name for the child property.

Comment: You can however do this for methods. So if he were to have a constant which was to use two different names but use an overridden accessor method `getParentProperty` then that would work, as he could call `parent::getParentProperty`.

Comment: @MGwynne: Indeed. However, the implementation of `Fruit::getParentProperty` again cannot access the "base" property because there is only one property, and it's effectively `virtual`. You would again have to resort to renaming one or both properties, so bringing functions into it doesn't really buy you anything.

Comment: It buys you a common method for accessing the property in each case. Although I agree it's not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

As you override the class attribute $parentproperty in the child class, I suppose that the value from the parent class is lost.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to access default value of non-static property of the parent class which was overridden in the child class:

```
class Orange extends Fruit
{
    protected $parentproperty = "child value";
    function showParentProperty()
    {
        $parentProps = get_class_vars(get_parent_class($this));
        return $parentProps['parentproperty'];
    }
}
```

This way you can access `protected` and `public` non-static properties of the parent class which is really handy when applying the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work this way. What you can do is declare properties in the parent, and then access them directly in the child as long as the child extends the parent. Then, in the child __constructor call the parent __constructor...

```
class fruit{
   protected $name;
   protected $type;

   __constructor($name, $type){
     $this->name = $name;
     $this->type = $type;
   }//end __constructor

}//end class

class thisFruit extends fruit{
   __constructor($name, $type){
      parent::__constructor($name, $type);
   }
}
```

You would use it
    $myFruit = new thisFruit("Orange", "Citrus");
    echo "This fruit is an ".$myFruit->name;

Hope this helps - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your child:

```
function showParentProperty()
{
    return parent::$parentproperty;
}
```

Comment: Not possible if the property on the parent is not `static`.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to do what you ask without a static property is to use reflexion api

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to use __get($value) in parent class and call it from child by
`public function __get($value){
    if($value == 'parentValue'){
        return parent::__get($value);
    }else{
        return $this->$value;
    }
}`
I used it in my current project and works fine.
 Kori